# memoize react component callback in a list

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

How can I memoize a callback generated in the map loop? This (obviously) gives an error:

```js
const SomeComponent = ({ items }: { items: ItemData[] }) => {
  const getItemCallback = (item: ItemData) => (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    //do something with item
  }

  return <div>
    {items.map(item => {
      const callback = useCallback(getItemCallback(item));
    
      return <Item title={item.title} itemCallback={callback} />
    })}

  </div>
}
```

[image]

Comment: put `const callback = useCallback(getItemCallback)` outside the loop? or just memoize the function while defining it like `const getItemCallback = useCallback((item) => {}, [])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `getItemCallback` in `useCallback` and pass it to the component:

```
const SomeComponent = ({ items }: { items: ItemData[] }) => {
  const getItemCallback = useCallback((item: ItemData) => (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    //do something with item
  }, []);

  return <div>
    {items.map(item => (
      <Item 
        key={item.key}
        item={item} 
        itemCallback={getItemCallback} 
        />
    ))}
  </div>
}
```

The component then calls the callback, and passes the `item` to create a new function wrapped with `useCallback`:

```
const Item = ({ item, itemCallback }) => {
  const callback = useCallback(itemCallback(item), []);
  
  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

Comment: This looks quite close to the through. What if dependencies of `itemCallback` are only available in `SomeComponent`, not on `Item`?

Comment: If it's relevant for all items, you can pass it with the original callback. If it's relevant only for this item, pass it as part of the props. However, if you don't experience performance issues, you're code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ItemList = ({ items }: { items: ItemData[] }) => {
  const getItemCallback = useCallback((item: ItemData) => (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    //do something with item
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(item => (
        <Item title={item.title} itemCallback={getItemCallback(item)} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const SomeComponent = ({ items }: { items: ItemData[] }) => {
  return <ItemList items={items} />;
};
```

Comment: It is always important to add at least a brief explanation of what your answer is doing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The a updated version of your code using

```
const SomeComponent = ({ items }: { items: ItemData[] }) => {
      const getItemCallback = (item: ItemData) => (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        //do something with item
      }
    
      return (
        <div>
          {items.map(item => {
            const callback = useMemo(() => getItemCallback(item), [item]);
            return <Item title={item.title} itemCallback={callback} />;
          })}
        </div>
      );
    };
```